# Saving Worksheet as New Workbook Using Cell Value as Title

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code:

```
Sub SaveFinalMTO()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Sheets("Final MTO").Select
Sheets("Final MTO").Copy

'grab the file name from b6:m6, put it in variable ThisFile
ThisFile = Sheets("Final MTO").Range("b6:m6").Value

Sheets("Final MTO").SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\owner\Desktop\" & ThisFile & ".xlsm"

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
ActiveWorkbook.Close

End Sub
```

Everything works fine to an extent.  The new workbook is created with the correct sheet.  The new file is opened but the file name is "Book1" instead of the values in range `B6:M6` which is a merged cell using a concatenate function.  I tried using an unmerged with just a value, I was still pulling up a

> run time error "13"

Any help solving this error would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Which line gives you the error? The SaveAs line?

Comment: just use `.Range("b6")`. More than one cell returns an array.  Type mismatch could be due to many reasons. Use 'Option Explicit'

Comment: The line giving me the error is Sheets("Final MTO").SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\owner\Desktop\" & ThisFile & ".xlsm"

Comment: I figured it out.  There is no "owner" file.  Duh.

Comment: **You should be declaring your variables** and using `Option Explicit` at the top of every module, ***always***, especially while learning, to help prevent issues like this.  ...also, note that `owner` is a folder, not a file.  It's important to get the terminology right early on, for the benefit of yourself and others. [Here](http://www.homeandlearn.org/) is a link to a tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, ashleedawg! Yes, a folder.  Typing without thinking.  I'll try not to make that mistake again. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to save as a macro enabled file type, then you have to specify that. Also, you can make the folder name dynamic using `Environ$`.

```
Sheets("Final MTO").SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\" & Environ$("Username") & "\Desktop\" & ThisFile & ".xlsm", xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled
```

[XlFileFormat Enumerations](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb241279(v=office.12).aspx)